# Compare 2 files and show differences if any

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have a function that will compare 2 files, and show any differences and that works great. However, if there are no differences, I want that stated also.

**Code**

```
dFile = "file1.txt"
master = "file2.txt"

with open(dFile) as f:
    t1 = f.read().splitlines()
    t1s = set(t1)

with open(master) as f:
    t2 = f.read().splitlines()
    t2s = set(t2)

for diff in t1s-t2s:
    if t1.index(diff) != "":
        print("Found Discrepancy")
        print("Line: " + str(t1.index(diff)), diff)
    else:
        print("No issues found")
```

**Output when there IS a difference:**

```
Found Discrepancy

Line: 1  Testing Differences

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**Output when there is NOT a difference:**

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the code like this -

```
for diff in t1s-t2s:
    if t1.index(diff) != "":
        print("Found Discrepancy")
        print("Line: " + str(t1.index(diff)), diff)
    else:
        print("No issues found")
```

Here if there are no differences, the loop will never be executed and you will never print the `No issues found`.

You should do it as -

```
if not t1s-t2s :
    print("No issues found")
for diff in t1s-t2s:
    if t1.index(diff) != "":
        print("Found Discrepancy")
        print("Line: " + str(t1.index(diff)), diff)
```

This will print no issues found when file is same, else print the discrepancy

Comment: That makes so much scene. The t1s-t2s was stopping everything from running... over looked that completely... thanks so much for the simple fix

Comment: @dwb Glad to help ! Do note that this will only output the words in file1 that do not match to any word in file2. Your question description says you need to compare two files and output if there are any differences. Your code only outputs it when file1 has words not present in file2 and not vice-versa

Comment: I should of clarified more. The goal is to see if File 1 is the same as File 2 (File 2 being the master)

Comment: @dwb https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-set-difference/ then just do t2s-t1s.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the end to

```
if not (t1s-t2s):
    print("No issues found")
for diff in t1s-t2s:
    if t1.index(diff) != "":
        print("Found Discrepancy")
        print("Line: " + str(t1.index(diff)), diff)
```

This will work between `t1s - t2s` will evaluate as true if it is nonempty only. Conversely, if it is empty, the body of the `for` loop won't be executed.